# How do you remove extra whitespace on the top of an input checkbox with custom box-shadow (Chrome 68)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, box-shadow

See image and jsfiddle below. It seems to have to do with the increase in font-size. Is there an alternative way to increase the size of the checkbox while maintaining a custom surrounding box-shadow on Chrome (68)? I've tried a few things.

[image: Input checkbox with custom box-shadow]

See: https://jsfiddle.net/tnpa6r80/

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  font-size: 20px;  
}

input[type='checkbox']:focus {
    border-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px red;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: and why increasing the font-size of a checkbox? it has no effect

Comment: @TemaniAfif It does make it bigger. See https://jsfiddle.net/tnpa6r80/ vs https://jsfiddle.net/tnpa6r80/8/ vs https://jsfiddle.net/tnpa6r80/7/

Comment: no they are all the same for me which is logical and I am also using chrome .. can you share a screenshot of the difference?

Comment: I am on a mac and the font size makes no difference and it is the cause of the extra space

Comment: I'm on a mac - 10.13.2 using chrome 68.0.3440.106

https://jsfiddle.net/tnpa6r80/12/

Comment: Chrome 69 on Windows the font-size does nothing but I do see the whitespace.

Comment: Here is what I see: https://imgur.com/a/jThaKfn

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the way in which you are increasing the size of the checkbox. Instead of using `font-size` use `-webkit-transform: scale(<insert your scale>);` and that should work. You can look an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/19L30kvr/

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out a solution that works. If anyone has an alternative or better solution please post it.

https://jsfiddle.net/19L30kvr/22/

```css
#input-container {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;   
}

#input-container:focus-within  {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px red;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  zoom: 2;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='input-container'>
  <input id='input' type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```